# Laravel 5.5 routes order error

Tags: laravel-5

I installed a fresh version of ***Laravel 5.5*** and this is some issue with web routes ordering:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});    
Auth::routes();    
Route::group(['prefix' => 'respond'], function () {


      Route::get('/{quiz}', 'RespondentController@show')
     ->middleware('auth');      
      Route::get('/save_answer2', 'RespondentController@save_answer2')
     ->middleware('auth'); 

});
```

> route respond/save_answer2 - error 404

if we change the order of routing and route `/save_answer2` will be above `/{quiz}` everything will be ok. Why is this?

Comment: you still have this problem ? and did you have the show method in the controller ?

Comment: yes, i have RespondentController@show and RespondentController@save_answer2

Comment: because in that order it's that will be trigred with `respond/save_answer2` not save_answer2 ! but you said you had 404 o.O

Comment: respond/save_answer2 -404 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you used prefix respond

Try `respond/save_answer2`

Comment: so for what we need then ['prefix' => 'respond'] ?

Comment: To prefix the set of urls inside the route group

Comment: Try this command and find the routes `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Use the route that is displayed in the list make sure you are using get method ie, Route::get